# Apex Test Failure: System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0 Stack Trace: Class.CaseExtensionTest.test_Attachment: line 136, column 1

Tags: apex, unit-test

Getting the Test Coverage error:

> Apex Test Failure: System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0 
>   Stack Trace: Class.CaseExtensionTest.test_Attachment:

```
 static testMethod void test_Attachment() {
      String var = [SELECT Agency_Id__c FROM Account WHERE Agency_Id__c != null][0].Agency_Id__c;
        System.runAs(gettestUser()) {

            Lease__c lease = new Lease__c();
            lease.Asset_Manager_Name__c = gettestUser().Name;
            lease.TENTID__c = var;
            lease.CriticalDateText__c = '01/02/2016';
            lease.Type__c = 'Expiry';
            lease.LEASID__c = '111';
            lease.Lease_Key__c = 'KEY:1';

            insert lease;

            record = getCaseRecord();
            params.put('Id',record.Id);
            resetPage();

            String tester = '';

            tester = '' + cntrl.agencies;
            tester = '' + cntrl.isAcquisition;
            tester = '' + cntrl.isEditable;
            tester = '' + cntrl.isEditMode;
            tester = '' + cntrl.isLocked;           

 cntrl.oCase.LeasedAddress__c = [Select Id FROM LeasedAddress__c ][0].Id;

            tester = '' + cntrl.LeasedAddress;
            tester = '' + cntrl.OperationalSpace;
            tester = '' + cntrl.isNew;
            tester = '' + cntrl.isReassign;
            cntrl.getattachments();
            tester = '' + cntrl.caseAttachmentList;
            tester = '' + cntrl.caseAttachments;
            cntrl.getintentionPreference();
            cntrl.oCase.IsRequestAboutExistingLease__c = 'No';
```

Comment: Getting  Error at.------ >   cntrl.oCase.LeasedAddress__c = [Select Id FROM LeasedAddress__c ][0].Id;

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post with any clarifications, and try to apply only tags which are actually relevant to your question.

Answer (score 3):

You're getting the error because this query `[Select Id FROM LeasedAddress__c]` is returning 0 results.

You have to create a leasedAddress__c record before you can query for it. The code you shared does not show you are doing this.

I'd also recomend using a @testSetup method and organizing your code a bit better as it currently looks like you either have see all data (not likely because of error) or you are creating records in several different places in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually insert `LeasedAddress__c` records. Note from the `Apex Developer Guide` (emphasis mine):

> ## [Isolation of Test Data from Organization Data in Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm)
>
> Starting with Apex code saved using Salesforce API version 24.0 and later, test methods don’t have access by default to pre-existing data in the organization, such as standard objects, custom objects, and custom settings data, and can only access data that they create. However, objects that are used to manage your organization or metadata objects can still be accessed in your tests such as:
>
> - User
> - Profile
> - Organization
> - AsyncApexJob
> - CronTrigger
> - RecordType
> - ApexClass
> - ApexTrigger
> - ApexComponent
> - ApexPage
>
> **Whenever possible, you should create test data for each test. You can disable this restriction by annotating your test class or test method with the `IsTest(SeeAllData=true)` annotation.**